# message box window using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to accomplish the following in my website:

There is a "Message User" button, when it is clicked I want to display a Message box to the user and have the following requirement:

1. The message box should not be a pop up window
2. The user Should still be able to see the page where button was clicked

I have seen this on other sites.

Is this accomplished using AJAX?

Comment: As you stated that you don't need a pop-up, can you provide an example link where you've seen it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the Ajax Control Toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is accomplished by using javascript - typically it's a hidden div on the page that is tied to the click event of your button - there are TONS of controls out there to do this (called dialog boxes) see:

[jQuery Dialog Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: Thanks, will I be able to put controls in the Dialog Box?

Comment: Yes - check out the source on that demo - it's just a div with a paragraph in there - you should be able to do whatever you want in there.  If you want an ASP server control then have a look at ComponentArt.com or Telerik.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use on button click if displaying message box using Ajax as:

string jv = "alert('Error Details: Duplicate Entry of Company Name ');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "alert", jv, false);
return;